# How can I check if Dynamically created Select Boxes have been selected

Tags: javascript

I have some code that has one contact select box hard coded and then if you click on a add button it adds more contacts. Each contact can be selected from a dropdown and give a location in at location text box.

I want on submit to be able to know if they have selected someone and if not I want to clear out the Location box as there cannot be a location if there is no contact.

```
<!--- The myContactCount variable is set in another part of javascript this is the current count plus one of the number of current select boxes. --->

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      var e='';
      var contactSelectedValue='';

      for(var i=1;1<myContactCount;i++){
         e = document.getElementById('myContactID_'+i);
         contactSelectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         /* I am trying to alert the value so I can then use a if statement to check for null or even change the 'Select a Contact' value to 0 and test for that. */

        alert(contactSelectedValue);
     }
   </script>

   <!--- the ID will be 1-100 depending on how many contacts they have added --->

   <select name="myContactID_#ID#">
      <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
      <option value="1">Abe</option>
      <option value="2">Barbara</option>
      <option value="3">Cavlin</option>
   </select>
```

---

So after they are created dynamically they code would look like this.

```
<select name="myContactID_1">
   <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
   <option value="1">Abe</option>
   <option value="2">Barbara</option>
   <option value="3" selected="selected">Cavlin</option>
</select>

<select name="myContactID_2">
   <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
   <option value="1">Abe</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">Barbara</option>
   <option value="3">Cavlin</option>
</select>


<select name="myContactID_3">
   <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Abe</option>
   <option value="2">Barbara</option>
   <option value="3">Cavlin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When the form is submitted, the values in the form as it is at the time it is submitted, is sent. This happens regardless of wether or not the elements have been inserted with javascript, so checking if anything is selected should be trivial, just see if it's part of the returned data from the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has couple of issues:-

`1<myContactCount` instead of `i<=myContactCount` and you are using name in the select and 
trying to fetch it by id.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39ZF9/)

#### Html

```
<select id="myContactID_1">
   <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
   <option value="1">Abe</option>
   <option value="2">Barbara</option>
   <option value="3" selected="selected">Cavlin</option>
</select>

<select id="myContactID_2">
   <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
   <option value="1">Abe</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">Barbara</option>
   <option value="3">Cavlin</option>
</select>


<select id="myContactID_3">
   <option value="">Select a Contact</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Abe</option>
   <option value="2">Barbara</option>
   <option value="3">Cavlin</option>
</select>
```

#### JS

```
 var e='';
      var contactSelectedValue='';

      for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
         e = document.getElementById('myContactID_'+i);
         contactSelectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         /* I am trying to alert the value so I can then use a if statement to check for null or even change the 'Select a Contact' value to 0 and test for that. */

        alert(contactSelectedValue);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks The ID was what I had overlooked... I was upgrading someone else's code. Good thing I typed it in with the mistake using the name. that was my main issue.